# Writing HTML that contains PHP tags to file

Tags: php, html, templates, file-io, tags

I think what I'm trying to do must be impossible; incredibly difficult; or pretty easy, and I just don't know how to express what I want correctly to Google.

What I want to do is the following:

For the purposes of templating, I am outputting HTML to a file.  However, I want the file to contain PHP tags - not the parsed value of the PHP code (this value will change based upon included scripts in the output file) - but the actual `<?php ?>` tags themselves - containing the unmodified code, such that the code is still executable at run time.

This is an example of what I want to get outputted:

```
<html>
      <body>
        <img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH;?>img.jpg" />
      </body>
   </html>
```

What I'm getting is a combination of things that are wrong, depending on which method I use.  Basically, I need to be able to write parsable PHP code to a HTML file.  Now, whether or not this is a good idea is debatable, and a subject I'm not too interested in at the moment.  I just want to know if a **sane** solution exists.

I came up with the following **insane** solution:

```
$content='<html><body><img src="zxzxzx?php echo IMG_PATH; ?qjqjqj" />';
file_put_contents($file,$content);

$command='perl -p -i.bktmp -e "s/zxzxzx/</g" '.$file.' 2>'.$path.'error.log';
$command2='perl -p -i.bktmp -e "s/qjqjqj/>/g" '.$file.' 2>'.$path.'error.log';
exec($command);
exec($command2);
```

Now, on one hand, this feels devilishly clever.  And, it also feels insane.  Is there a better/possible way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the code that actually saves the file? @Rottingham is correct with the idea about it needing to be saved as a .php file.

Comment: If you wrap a string in single quotes `'`, then PHP treats it as a string literal - it won't try to parse it at all . You should just be able to set your content to `'<html><body><img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH; ?>" />'` and have it output the PHP tag.

Comment: The server is set up to interpret `html` as `php`.  This was a necessary evil as I am working with a large (amazingly so) site with all static html files, hand coded.  The code is way too long to post - but the output is all being done with `file_put_contents()`;

Comment: @andrewsi - can you show an example?  I have found what you say not to be true.

Comment: @user1167442 - I just tried `echo ('<html><body><img src="<?php echo IMG_PATH; ?>" />')`, and it printed out the php tags, as tags. Also, see Marc B's much more informative answer.

Comment: @andrewsi - Your right.  I think my problem is actually different than what I thought it was.  See my comment below Marc B's answer.  Perhaps you can offer something here?

Answer (score 3):

You are misinterpreting how PHP operates. The following code:

```
<?php

echo 'This string <?php echo 'contains' ?> some PHP code';
```

Will produce as output

```
This string <?php echo 'contains' ?> some PHP code
```

You will **NOT** get:

```
This string contains some PHP code
```

PHP's parser is not recursive. PHP code embedded inside PHP code, e.g. inside a string, as it is above, is NOT treated as PHP code - it'll just be some text.

If you want to write out some PHP code, then just write it out:

```
$string = 'This string <?php echo 'contains' ?> some PHP code';
file_put_contents('file.php', $string);
```

You don't need to take any special measures for the PHP code in the string to be written out, it'll just "work".

Now, that being said, if you ever put that string into a context where it COULD be evaluated as code, e.g.

```
eval($string);
```

then you WILL have to take measures to keep PHP from seeing the opening `<?php` tag and switching into "code mode".

Comment: I verified what you wrote in a quick test script, and it works.  I upvoted it, its a good answer.  But I'm having trouble, and hopefully, there is a simple solution.  I'm using `DOMDocument` to parse all the images in an html file, and replacing there source using `DOMDocument->setAttribute()`.  When I put the `<?php echo...?>` in the `src` attribute, the opening and closing tags get url encoded, thus rendering the code unparsable.  I assume this is happening when I am executing `DOMDocument->saveHTML()`.  Does that make sense.  Do you have a workaround/solution to that?

Comment: that's to be expected. `<?php` would be interpreted as an HTML tag if it wasn't encoded as `&lt;?php`. you can use htmlspecialchars/html_entity_decode to convert back and forth if need be.

Comment: In theory, I get it.  In practice, I am not able to get it to work. After it is saved from html to text string - if I use `html_entity_decode()` during the `file_put_contents()` call, it almost works, but there are still url_encoded spaces inside the php tags.  Is that clear?  I love your answer, but I can't seem to apply it.  Do you have any further tips?

Comment: url encoding as well? You should investigate where the text is coming from, because there's usually NO point in both url-encoding AND html-entity-encoding text.

Comment: its coming originally from a static html file, and then getting parsed by javascript and submitted via ajax.  When it gets loaded by javascript, the php variables are converted to proper values and/or replaced.  Then it is submitted to php as a simple html string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead your HTML file needs to be a PHP file. See below:

File: test.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <? echo 'My PHP embedded in HTML'; ?>
        <img src="<? echo $imagePath; ?>"/>
    </body>
</html>
```